# How to display create page/form within a separate controllers show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to have the ability to create an order directly from the listings show page instead of having to be directed to a new orders page.

I have a Listing (listingcontroller show method) which can be purchased by clicking a button to go to an orders page (orderscontroller create method).

In what way can I have the order form directly on the listings show page?

I have tried adding the form, but I get error:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
<%= form_for([@listing, @order]) do |form| %>
```

When I take the Orders controller create method and put it in the Listings Controller Show method i get this error:

```
Couldn't find Listing without an ID
```

Here's the form_for I want within the Listings Show Page:

```
    <%= form_for([@listing, @order]) do |form| %>
....
```

Orders Controller create:

```
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    @seller = @listing.user
    @order.listing_id = @listing.id
    @order.buyer_id = current_user.id
    @order.seller_id = @seller.id

...
```

Routes:

```
  resources :listings do
    resources :orders
end
```

listing model:

```
  has_many :orders
```

category model:

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :listings
```

I tried taking the orders create method and injecting it into the Listings show method with "def create" and without.  I put "@listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])" ahead of the create method (when using "def create" and i would still get the error it needs an id.  Even when I get that error, at the bottom of the webpage the request shows the listing ID is there.

I tried using a hidden field in the form but didn't work for me.

Do I need to do something to the controllers or is there a way to load the :listing_id into the form somehow.  This is probably something very quick and simple for some of you but why won't it load on the listings show page, but loads fine in the orders create page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy approach.

Your show action in **listing_controller.rb** should have the following code:

```
def show
  @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
  @order  = @listing.orders.build
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Your views/listings/**show.erb** should have the following code

```
<%= form_for(@order, url: listing_orders_path(@listing)) do |f| %> 
. 
. 
. 
<%= end %>
```

This way you create an order to the listing (in memory) before you submit the form. You can add the listing id as a hidden field.

After submit the order you modify your **orders_controller.rb** this way:

```
def create
   @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
   @order = @listing.orders.build(params[...]) #select the params you need for the order creation. Since you create the order directly to the listing you don't need to add the listing_id to the order.

   if @order.save
            #do something
   else
            #do something
   end
end
```

Keep in mind that using params[] directly you have security problems, please check about mass assignment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/security.html

Comment: Using a single parameter from the params is not a security issue. The problem is when you assign the entire params hash to a model without whitelisting it. So the original code is fine - but yours has a mass assignment vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks, i know my code has mass assignment that's why i refer to the security guide, otherwise i should declare some extra methods to permit attributes what is not the fact of the solution.

Comment: Why am I still getting the same error: "Couldn't find Listing without an ID"... I then define it in the orders controller as:     @order.listing_id = @listing.id
but then i get the error: "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass" ---- I also tried using hidden class :listing_id which passes the param through as well with the correct listing_id

Comment: Mmm that error tells you that for some reason your listing isn't declared or even created, please be sure you create a correct listing before you submit the order form.

Comment: When I add @listing back into the form_for and press submit, the page doesn't go anywhere and says "no template found for orders create".  Aside from trying that method which isn't viable probably, how would the listing not be created correctly when the orders are created successfully when created on their own page?

Comment: @NicolásNisoria would you care to take a look at my app? I have it on github.  I can show you what I'm dealing with directly.  If so, can you create a chat on here for me to send to you? (I would but I don't see the ability for me to create a chat here.... might need to be certain rank)

Comment: I don't mind to take a look to your work but I can't create chats, maybe you can paste your github repository here

Comment: I'm fairly new at coding(about a month) so my thought process is elementary with all of this at the moment but the only issue i can think of is when the listing is created (listing new method) but i can't be sure.

Comment: Ok, i'm looking at your repository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182984/discussion-between-uno-and-nicolas-nisoria).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using `AJAX` call, where you will pass the url of `orders` action and other params. There will be no reload of page and you'll get the functionality right on the listings page.

[Here](https://launchschool.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails) is the link to have a look - How AJAX calls work.

Comment: This could work but i would still need to recode my controllers to work like this because I would be rendering the form from the orders controller to the listings controller show page  <<< I do believe so.  Right now I only have the orders created on the orders controllers create page.. I need do, and have unsuccessfully so far, create the ability to create an order directly from the listings show page

Comment: It doesn't matter what controller you're calling and from where. You just have to pass the url to the AJAX call and it'll work. Try to take some tutorial regarding this. I'm hopfull that it'll help you :)